# Python script autorun on windows startup

Tags: python, windows, winreg

I am trying to create a script that will display a page in chrome on startup. That is, I am trying to run a python script on startup. I am using the `winreg` module to do so.

Here is my script to add a my page display script on startup:

```
import winreg  
import os    
import sys, traceback          

def AddToRegistry(): 


    pth = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(path_to_page_display_script)) 

    s_name="test.py"     

    address=os.path.join(pth,s_name)  

    try:
        open = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, r"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", reserved=0, access = winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS) 

        winreg.SetValueEx(open,"pytest",0,winreg.REG_SZ,address) 

        winreg.CloseKey(open)

    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)

if __name__=="__main__": 
    AddToRegistry()
```

Here is my page display script:

```
import webbrowser

url = 'http://docs.python.org/'

chrome_path = 'path_to_chrome/chrome.exe %s'

webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)
```

The script runs fine without any errors but on restarting my machine, the chrome does not open up by itself nor does it display the page. Basically, my script does not run. What is wrong ? Kindly help me out.

Comment: Where did you put your first script? How do you call it on windows boot?

Comment: Have you tried using a scheduled task?

Comment: @FlorianBernard I put my first script in a folder on my desktop. The path for that constitutes the `path_to_display_page_script` parameter in the above code.

Comment: @EcSync No I haven't tried that. Through a bit of research I found that using the registry editor method is a better option.

Comment: @Vai you need to put your script in a specific folder. https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.howtogeek.com/208224/how-to-add-programs-files-and-folders-to-system-startup-in-windows-8.1/amp/

Comment: @FlorianBernard That is my use case, I do not want to use the startup folder, hence the registory approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't with your script. It's with your registry key.

You need to tell windows to invoke `Python.exe C:\path_to_script\test.py`, not `test.py`.

So instead of this:

This:

```
path_to_python_exe = "C:\\python\\python38";
address=os.path.join(pth,s_name)  
address = os.path.join(path_to_python_exe, "python.exe") + " " + address;
```

Or if Python.exe is guaranteed to be in your PATH, simply this:

```
address = "Python.exe" + " " + os.path.join(pth,s_name)
```

Comment: Yep. It works like a charm now. You were right, I needed to invoke the script. Thanks a ton buddy.